# Any use case of different axis in tf.layers.batch_normalization?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any use case of different axis(default axis=-1 for h,w,c dim order) in [tf.layers.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/layers/batch_normalization)?

Comment: As said in the docs, `For instance, after a Convolution2D layer with data_format="channels_first", set axis=1 in BatchNormalization.`

Comment: Yes, this is trivial, but any other use cases, for example axis=2, i.e. not first or last dimension?